# SSRS Reporting loads slowly the 1st report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssrs-2008

I have a website(asp.net) which displays ssrs reports. Howevery everytime that I try to run the report from the website it takes about 2 min to load, but if I click on the report again , it will load up in seconds. I have tried to run a query that is used by the report and I get the results in second as well.

Is there any configuaration that I need to change or any tsql code that I need to add?

I have gone through to solutions provided here on stackoverflow  but still had no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems to be an SSRS issue. There is nothing wrong with your report.

Its "normal" that SSRS takes more time to load the first time you access it after a long time of inactivity. The issue is caused by the way how SSRS works and SSRS regularly restarts application domain after specific time period. After the application domain is restarted, then upon first request to the SSRS it needs to load all the settings and it takes quite a long time.

[This](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2011/07/solving-issue-long-starting-report-ssrs-2008/) blog show's an work around for the situation

Comment: I tried what has been suggested(adding powersehll script and shedule a task)on the link but I still get the same time of waiting for the 1st report.Is there anything else I can do it?

Comment: maybe increase the  <RecycleTime>720</RecycleTime> tag to a (much) bigger values (that's in minutes) on the rsreportserver.config file. I didnt try because honestly it doesn't bother me, it only happens once a day

Comment: I did changed to <RecycleTime>1500</RecycleTime> as suggested on the page. :(

Comment: did you restart SSRS? Also, is the delay happening every time or just once every 1500 minute?

Comment: well is working ... I think the restart made a difference...will see how it does for the next few days...Thanks for your help

Comment: oh you definitely have to restart SSRS so it can read the config files (specially rsreportserver.config which is the main one)